# moment.js time changes when formatted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am experiencing some weird behaviour when using moment.js. I have an object with a date and timezone. When I type `moment(obj.start_time).tz(timeZoneName)`, I get a time [Image showing time before formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKJVX.png). However, when I use the **format** method, the value of the time changes, i.e. `moment(obj.start_time).tz(timeZoneName).format('hh:mm a')` results in a different time (in this case a time that was 8:51pm before formatting, changed to 12:51pm automatically).

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ + [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you're seeing is an internal `UTC` value, moment.js must keep this since the UTC offset may vary for any individual timezone that observes Daylight saving time.

For example, the UTC offset for Los Angeles varies from Pacific Standard Time (PST, UTC -8 hours) to Pacific Daylight Time (PDT, UTC -7 hours).

The value you display while formatting is the equivalent time in the timezone you're converting to.

So it's 8:51pm in the UTC timezone, while it's 12:51pm in the timezone you're converting to:

```js
let ts = "2021-07-05T20:51:00Z";
let timeZoneName = "Etc/GMT+8";
let m = moment(ts).tz(timeZoneName);
console.log("Moment value:", m);
console.log("UTC time:", moment(ts).tz("UTC").format('hh:mm a'));
console.log("Local time:", m.format('hh:mm a'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```